# Use gdb inside docker container for remote debugging in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, docker, gdb

Is it actually possible to configure the eclipse IDE to use the gdb debugger inside a docker container to do remote debugging?

So

- Eclipse IDE is on my host
- The cross toolchain and debugger are inside my container
- The debug binary runs on a remote device.

I am configuring "C/C++ Remote Application" in Eclipse and my gdb path is set to

docker run -it --rm --privileged -p 5000:5000 docker-gdb

After hitting the debug button in Eclipse the gdbserver is starting and listening on port 5000 on the target system. The entrypoint of my image is gdb itself. Inside a shell, the remote debugging is working fine.
But Eclipse gives the error "the input device is not a TTY" or "Timed out trying to launch GDB" when the docker command runs with "-i" instead of "-it".